# Why is .every() not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've gathered an Array (I think) of required form elements, and have added 'blur' listener.

```
    var formInputs = $(':input').filter('[required]');
  formInputs.each(function(i) {
    $(this).on('blur', function() { // Each time we leave a 'required' field, check to see if we can activate the 'submit' button.
      submitEnabler(formInputs);
    });
  });
```

So, once someone has left one of these fields, I want to run through this array using .every() and check if the fields are valid - that is if they have a 'success' class that I have defined.

```
function isValid(input) {
  return input.hasClass('is_glowing_success');
}

function submitEnabler(inputs) {

  console.log(inputs.every(isValid));
}
```

I keep getting back:

```
Uncaught TypeError: inputs.every is not a function
    at submitEnabler
```

Now, I could do something like this...

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if ($(inputs[i]).hasClass('is_glowing_success')) {
      console.log('yes');
    } else {
      console.log('no');
    }
  }
```

But, why can't I just use: [Array.Prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) ?

Comment: To improve code, you can write `$(':input[required]').blur(submitHandler);` and make changes in `submitHandler` to access `inputs`.

Comment: @Tushar I did:   $(':input[required]').blur(submitHandler(formInputs));
Works great! Thanks! The previous code did feel a bit 'icky.'

Comment: It should be `.blur(function() { submitHandler(formInputs); });`. Otherwise, the handler will be called immediately and not on `blur` event.s

Comment: Absolutely correct. I got that figured out now, and makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery does not have a `.every()` method. `.every` is defined at `Array.prototype`.

You can use `.toArray()` to convert jQuery object to an `Array`, within `.every()` callback function pass current `DOM` element to `jQuery()` to get jQuery object representation of element where `.hasClass()` can be chained.

```
function submitEnabler(inputs) {
  console.log(inputs.toArray().every(isValid));
}

function isValid(input) {
  return $(input).hasClass('is_glowing_success');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Because jQuery objects have no `every` method, and `formInputs` is a jQuery object.

If you want an array instead, call [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get one.

> I've gathered an Array (I think) of required form elements...

No, it's just  jQuery object. jQuery objects are very *array-like*, but they aren't arrays. Worse, they have some array-like methods (such as [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)) that call their callbacks with **different** arguments than the equivalent `Array.prototype` methods.

In `isValid`, you'd need to handle the fact you're now dealing with a raw DOM element, which means either wrapping it with a jQuery object and using `hasClass`:

```
function isValid(input) {
  return $(input).hasClass('is_glowing_success');
}
```

or using the DOM's `classList`:

```
function isValid(input) {
  return input.classList.contains('is_glowing_success');
}
```

That latter works on all modern browsers, but not all older ones. However, it can be polyfilled on older browsers. More about that [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: Ah, so using get() might *get* me the Array I am after so that I can use that method...ok, will try after some time. Thanks.

Comment: @guest271314 I was thinking the same thing, but the nice thing about `.every()` is that it stops looping as soon as it encounters a failure, while `.filter` has to check every element and build a new jQuery collection.

Comment: @Barmar `$.each()` and `.each()`  offer mechanism to stop iteration with `return false` https://jsfiddle.net/Ldnbehy7/ ; have rarely used the pattern, here.

Comment: @guest271314 But `$.each` doesn't return a useful result, it just returns the original collection (useful for chaining, but not for telling whether the tests were succesful)

Comment: @Barmar Yes, one reason why have not used pattern frequently. Would use same approach described for `.filter()` pattern; that is, increment a variable from `0` to `N`, check if `N` is equal to `.length` of collection at line following `$.each()`. Or define a `Boolean`, if condition is met within `$.each()` callback set `Boolean` to the opposite of existing defined `Boolean`, call `return false`, then check `Boolean` variable value at line following `$.each()`. It could also be composed as `return (bool = <condition ? true : false>)` or `return (bool = <condition>)`

Comment: @Barmar That would be a useful `$.fn` method or function defined at `$` object iteself. That is a jQuery method which break when condition is met and returns a `Boolean` with `context` set to original selector, or capable of being set to a specific selector or object; or original object or selector set to expected parameter of callback function within method. How to phrase such a Question? Is the above sufficient?

Comment: @guest271314 Context can't be returned by a function in JS.

Comment: @Barmar `Reflect.apply()` or `jQuery.proxy()` can set the context of a function call. Unless using the term `context` inappropriately,  above?

Comment: @guest271314 That's not the same as a function returning a context. When you chain functions, the context of the next function is always the value that was returned by the previous one. And the chained function has to be a method of the value that was returned.

Comment: @guest271314 If you return a proxy, you can't also return a boolean.

Comment: @Barmar `context` in respect to `this` within the function. That is different from the value returned from the function, correct?

Comment: A proxy is a function, so you can't chain it (except to use function methods like `.apply`), you have to call it, and it has the desired context.  But it still can't also be a Boolean.

Comment: @Barmar `$("selector").meetsCondition(condition, function /* this function breaks when condition is met */(bool /* Boolean result of condition parameter  */, "selector" as object /* or set different context:this within function, optionally with elements removed from "selector" */) {//do stuff}).hide(/* this:"selector" */)`

Comment: That's very different, using a callback that receives the boolean. It's essentially a form of Wheeler's Law: Any problem in CS can be solved by adding a level of indirection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142979/discussion-between-guest271314-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use array.map()
for example where `input` is the array
`input.map(function(input){
  return $(input).hasClass('is_glowing_success');
 });`

> this is just an example read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control)

Comment: I looked at that...but I'm not really trying to generate another array after processing each element like map does. Thanks.

Comment: This will return an array of booleans. That won't tell you if every element matches.