# Check if all elements satisfy a condition with for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I basically try to check if all input fields are valid by using the following code:

```
 addData (input){

   var isValid = false;    

   for (var i = 0, ii = input.length; i < ii; ++i) {          

      if ($('#' + input[i].id).hasClass('valid')) {
          isValid = true;              
      }
   }

   if (isValid) {
     //do stuff
   }
 }
```

In total the input.length is 3 and I want to check if all 3 input fields are valid. In my example, it just checks the last input element. In [related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470660/check-if-all-elements-satisfy-a-condition), I couldn`t find a way to solve it with a for-loop. Can anybody help?

> Thanks for all the helpful answers: Finally, I adjusted Máté Safranka's answer:
>
> ```
> var isValid = input.toArray().every(element => $('#' + element.id).hasClass('valid'))
> ```
>
> with `.toArray()` to convert jQuery object to an `Array` >> [see
>   here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698534/why-is-every-not-a-function) for more information. Defining `true` or `false` is not
>   needed anylonger.

Comment: If you already have the inputs in a variable, there's no need to re-find them using their ID (they may not have an id), eg: `if ($(input[i]).hasClass("valid")) { `

Comment: `var i = 0, ii = input.length; i < ii; ++i` Are you using `i` or `ii`?

Comment: Your code determines whether *any* input is valid; if at least one of them is, then `isValid` is set to `true`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus look again, `i` is used for the loop, `ii` for the exit condition (it's an unconventional, but valid way to set the bounds) (unconventional as it some people think it's a mistake...)

Comment: @freedomn-m That's why I asked. I didn't say it was a mistake, but IMHO it's an incredibly bad idea to use two variables so similar in their name. It's a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `input` is an array, you can use `.every()`:

```
var isValid = input.every(it => $('#' + it.id).hasClass('valid'));
```

If `input` isn't an array, you can convert it to an array with `Array.from()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

**Note:** As pointed out in the comments, this works in IE10 and later. This shouldn't be a problem most of the time (Windows 10 ships with IE11 and Edge, and theoretically every commercial end-user should have upgraded by now), but worth noting in case you have to support legacy platforms.

Comment: Always good to see "new" features, but worth noting browser support incase it *is* an issue: https://caniuse.com/#search=every (show all) (IE10+)

Comment: @freedomn-m That is why there are polyfills ;) Do not hold yourself back because of outdated browsers.

Comment: @str agreed, but I see so many questions here along the lines of "this code doesn't work `=>` ...") ... 500 comments later:  "oh yeah, I'm using IE6"... :)

Comment: I adjusted your code and now it´s working fine: I set `var isValid = true; ` and `if (!input.toArray().every(element => $('#' + element.id).hasClass('valid'))) {
                isValid = false;
            }                      `

Comment: That's not necessary though, `every()` returns `true` if all elements satisfy the criteria, and `false` if they don't, and that's literally what the value of `isValid` needs to be. So it should work just with `var isValid = input.toArray().every(element => $('#' + element.id).hasClass('valid'));`

Answer (score 4):

You never set `isValid` to false, so as long as at least one of the inputs is valid the result will be valid.

Better to swap the true/false and check for any invalid ones, eg:

```
addData (input){

 var isValid = true;    

 for (var i = 0, ii = input.length; i < ii; ++i) {          
   if (!$('#' + input[i].id).hasClass('valid')) {
      isValid = false;              
   }
 }

 if (isValid) {
  //do stuff
 }
}
```

---

Note: there are alternatives to using a loop, but this is to answer the explicit question of fixing the loop in OPs question.

Comment: Since I asked for  a solution with for-loop, this answer is correct. However, I attached my final solution to my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You got it wrong. You're assuming invalid until an element is valid. And you should assume valid until one element is invalid:

```
addData (input){
   var isValid = true;    

   for (var i = 0, ii = input.length; i < ii; ++i) {          

      if (!($('#' + input[i].id).hasClass('valid'))) {
          isValid = false;              
      }
   }

   if (isValid) {
     //do stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the others have said, you need to start off with `isValid` set to `true` and then as of the first invalid field, set it to `false` and break the loop.

But if `input` is really an array, I'd use `input.every` instead:

```
addData (input){
    if (input.every(function(element) { return $(element).hasClass('valid'); })) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

`Array#every` calls the callback for the items in the array, returning `true` if the callback returns a truthy value for all of them, or returning `false` (and stopping immediately) if the callback ever returns a falsy value.

Or you could use jQuery's `filter`:

```
addData (input){
    if ($(input).filter(':not(.valid)').length === 0) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

---

`Array#every` is more concise if you can use an ES2015+ arrow function:

```
addData (input){
    if (input.every(element => $(element).hasClass('valid'))) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`and`ing `true` with `isValid` (as opposed to assigning `true` directly) will make it so the first false value will make the whole condition false. Just be sure to start with `isValid` as true before the loop.

```
isValid = true;

// inside the loop

isValid = isValid && true;
```

Comment: Because `isValid` starts off `false`, that expression will never be `true`.

Comment: @Pointy yeah, I noticed just before you wrote that